# The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, non-nullable

I am following a Flutter tutorial that has such a following code, but code doesn't work on my computer, and I don't know how to fix it:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;

  CartItem({
    @required this.id,
  });
}
```

But I get such these errors:

```
The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter
{String id}
```

Comment: you're telling "id" that it can never be null... it should be "String?" instead of "String". I'll recommend you reading more about null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety Also, "@required" is now "required". You're using a newest version of Flutter and that example is old.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla: What is the difference between using `late` before the variable or `?` mark after it?

Comment: "late" is just like the word is saying, you'll init the variable "late" instead of during object construction but it can only be initialized once. Optional means that the object can also be null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options depending on your own project...

**Option1:** Make `id` nullable, you can keep `@required` or remove it.

```
class CartItem {
  final String? id;

  CartItem({
    this.id,
  });
}
```

**Option2:** Give a default (non-null) value to id

```
class CartItem {
  final String id;

  CartItem({
    this.id="",
  });
}
```

more in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181838/flutter-required-keyword)

Answer (score 6):

The latest dart version now supports sound [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety). The tutorial must be using an old version.

To indicate that a variable might have the value null, just add ? to its type declaration:

```
class CartItem {
  final String? id = null;
  CartItem({
     this.id,
   });
  }
```

or

```
class CartItem {
  final String? id;
  CartItem({
     this.id,
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace `@required this.id` with `required this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class City {
  int id;
  String name;
  String imageUrl;
  bool isPopular;

  City(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.isPopular});
}
```